# Add data to nested object using dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, object

I have an empty object structured like so :

```
let users = {
  "type1": {
      "group1": {
          "role1": {}
      },
      "group2": {
          "role2": {},
          "role3": {},
          "role4": {}
      },
  },
  "type2": {
      "group1": {
          "role1": {}
      },
      "group2": {
          "role2": {}
      },
      "group3": {
          "role3": {},
          "role4": {}
      }
  }
};
```

I am then fetching my users with an associated type, group and role for each one.
I would like to dynamically add my users to my object above in the right type/group/role combination as they are stored in variables.

I tried something like this but this is wrong:

```
fetchedUsers.forEach(user => {
  users[user.type][user.group][user.role].push(user.email);
})
```

Is there a way to do this similar to what I tried ?

Comment: Those roles are (empty) _objects_. You can't _push_ something into an object, only an array since [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is an array method.

Comment: The closest analog to `Array#push` is [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) though it doesn't modify the target object in place, so you will still need to do some reconstructive work.

Comment: I know I can't I am searching for the closest way to do this but with an object @Andy

Comment: I was just pointing out _why_ your code doesn't work. It would help to see what your expect your updated object should look like. Should a role look like this: `role: { name: 'Bob', role: 'admin' }` where there is only one role assigned to it, or `role: [{ name: 'Bob', role: 'admin'}, { name: 'Jo', role: 'user' }]` where there are many roles assigned to an array. How you want your output to look depends solely on what that structure is meant to look like. @Ryan

Comment: @Ryan I added a version with one email per role, keyed emails and an array of emails

Comment: Yes this works well it is the same way than taki's answer this is what I needed thank you !

Answer (score 4):

You cannot push to an object. Your role is not an array

```js
let users = { 
"type1": { "group1": { "role1": {} },
           "group2": { "role2": {}, "role3": {}, "role4": {}},},
"type2": { "group1": { "role1": {} },
           "group2": { "role2": {}},
           "group3": { "role3": {}, "role4": {}}}};

const fetchedUsers = [
  {"type":"type1","group": "group2", "role":"role3", "email":"x@useremail.com"},
  {"type":"type2","group": "group1", "role":"role1", "email":"y@useremail.com"}
];

fetchedUsers.forEach(
  ({type,group,role,email}) => users[type][group][role].email = email
);
console.log(users)
```

If you have more than one email per role, you need to make some keys

```js
let users = { 
"type1": { "group1": { "role1": {} },
           "group2": { "role2": {}, "role3": {}, "role4": {}},},
"type2": { "group1": { "role1": {} },
           "group2": { "role2": {}},
           "group3": { "role3": {}, "role4": {}}}};

const fetchedUsers = [
  {"type":"type1","group": "group2", "role":"role3", "email":"x@useremail.com"},
  {"type":"type2","group": "group1", "role":"role1", "email":"y@useremail.com"},
  {"type":"type2","group": "group1", "role":"role1", "email":"z@useremail.com"}
];

fetchedUsers.forEach(
  ({type,group,role,email}) => {
    const currentRole = users[type][group][role]
    const len = Object.entries(currentRole).length
    currentRole[`email${len}`] = email
});
console.log(users)
```

or use an array

```js
let users = { 
"type1": { "group1": { "role1": {} },
           "group2": { "role2": {}, "role3": {}, "role4": {}},},
"type2": { "group1": { "role1": {} },
           "group2": { "role2": {}},
           "group3": { "role3": {}, "role4": {}}}};

const fetchedUsers = [
  {"type":"type1","group": "group2", "role":"role3", "email":"x@useremail.com"},
  {"type":"type2","group": "group1", "role":"role1", "email":"y@useremail.com"},
  {"type":"type2","group": "group1", "role":"role1", "email":"z@useremail.com"}
];

fetchedUsers.forEach(
  ({type,group,role,email}) => {
    const currentRole = users[type][group][role]
    currentRole.emails = currentRole.emails || []
    currentRole.emails.push(email)
});
console.log(users)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `users[user.type][user.group][user.role]` is an object you can't use `push()`

If you initialise the empty role structures as arrays it should work.

```
let users = {
  "type1": {
      "group1": {
          "role1": []
      },
      "group2": {
          "role2": [],
          "role3": [],
          "role4": []
      },
  },
  "type2": {
      "group1": {
          "role1": []
      },
      "group2": {
          "role2": []
      },
      "group3": {
          "role3": [],
          "role4": []
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: This works well indeed, but I also need a way to keep roles as an object unhappily...

Comment: Alright. Then I'd probably do something like users[user.type][user.group][user.role][user.email] = user.email

this will sett each row in a role like {foo@bar.com: 'foo@bar.com', bar@bar.com: 'bar@bar.com'} etc.

Comment: Alright yes thank you this works as I wanted !